# TSQL stored procedure to read data from 2 tables and insert result into 3rd table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I have 3 tables:
Outlets (Out_id, Out_name, Out_Latitude, Out_Longitude)
Competition (Comp_Name, comp_Latitude, comp_Longitude)
Mapping (Out_Id, Out_Name, Comp_Name, Comp_Distance)

For each of the Out_ID I want to calculate the radial distance corresponding to each competition and if the radial distance is less than 5KM then the corresponding details should be inserted to the Mapping Table.

Example sample data
Outlet

| Out_id | Out_name | Out_Latitude | Out_Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 32.445 | 72 |
| 2 | DEF | 56.667 | 78.332 |

Competition

| Comp_Name | comp_Latitude | comp_Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PQR | 13.334 | 45.662 |
| UVW | 12.445 | 78.587 |

So for out_ID 1 if the Radial distance is less than 5 for both the competition and for Out_Id 2 only the first competition radial distance is less than 5 then the mapping table should look like below:

Mapping

| Out_Id | Out_Name | Comp_Name | Comp_Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | PQR | 4.2 |
| 1 | ABC | UVW | 3 |
| 2 | DEF | PQR | 1 |

Formula used for distance calculation is below

Comp_Distance = (sqrt(power((comp_Latitude-Out_Latitude),2) + Power((comp_Longitude-Out_Longitude),2)))*111

How can I achieve this using T-SQL Stored procedure on synapse dedicated pool.  All the data are dummy data here.

Comment: could you please explain how `Comp_Distance` is measured? If I know the formula I may have a solution.

Comment: I Just want to use simple formula for the distance calculation i.e. 
Comp_Distance = (sqrt(power((comp_Latitude-Out_Latitude),2) + Power((comp_Longitude-Out_Longitude),2)))*111

@AmirAliSam If you help with the answer now that could be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out that the formula returns in meter or kilometer or etc. but I suppose you need to use something like this:

```
insert Mapping (Out_Id, Out_Name, Comp_Name, Comp_Distance)
select Out_Id, Out_Name, Comp_Name, Comp_Distance
from
(
  select
    o.Out_Id, o.Out_Name, c.Comp_Name,
    (sqrt(power((c.comp_Latitude - o.Out_Latitude), 2) + 
    power((c.comp_Longitude - o.Out_Longitude), 2))) * 111 as Comp_Distance
  from Outlets o
  cross join Competition c
) q
where Comp_Distance < 5
```

**note:** I suppose that the formula returns in kilometers.

Comment: This is working absolutely fine.. Thanks a lot for the quick help.  @Amir

Comment: @Sipun Happy to hear that, so I'll be glad if you mark it as the correct answer. Good Luck :)